# Why can I not navigate back to my original activity from a different activity triggered from push notification intent?

Tags: android, push-notification

My app has 2 activities: a main activity, and a detail activity. When I click a button on main it generates a push notification which when clicked brings up the details page.

The problem is, I do not believe I've configured anything to suggest that the activity should open with any different launch properties other than standard nor are their any flags set to suggest my activity open differently either. However when the notification is clicked and the new activity opens, when I click the back button I am taken back to the homescreen and no active tasks are available any longer.

I've noticed through experimentation that if I direct the intent triggered by the notification to go to back to the main activity instead of the detail activity it operates as I would expect. I can click the button on the first instance of main activity to fire the notification, click the notification to bring up the second instance of main activity, then press back to go back to the original instance of Main activity. It even has the correct state of details represented in the original (a text box populated with what I provided to trigger the first notification to say).

I've also found that if I direct the intent to fire the detail activity but set the affinity associated w/ the activity to something else that it SORT OF works by just creating a new task w/ that activity as the sole activity associated w/ the task. But this isn't what I want nor is it what I think should be happening anyway.

EDIT: I've added a button that takes me to the details activity through a standard intent. This works as intended. I've also added a button to the details activity that generates a notification to the Main Activity operating on the same logic as the button on Main that fires the notification to go to the Details Activity except with the intent class changed. Clicking this generates the notification, and pushes the main activity onto the already existing task stack as is standard.

So it seems like the issue is related to the Detail activity being targeted by the pending intent but I haven't figured out exactly what yet and following the details in the android website is of no help (though this is obvious as it's where I started from originally)

Code:

Generates the push notification (found on main activity)

```
fun generatePush2(view: View){
    var generalTapIntent = Intent(this, ActivityDetail::class.java)
    var pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, generalTapIntent, 0);

    var notificationId = 0;
    var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Instant Message")
            .setContentText(txt_notification.text)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) //sets the event to fire when notification is clicked
            .setAutoCancel(true) //Removes notification when user taps it

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)){
            notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Android Manifest details (for proof)

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityDetail">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override the onBackPressed() like this:

```
public void onBackPressed()  
{  
    this.startActivity(new Intent(DetailActivity.this,MainActivity.class));  
    return;  
}
```

if you want the main activity to look different than default you can still pass some data through the intent and display it the way you want using :

**Detail Activity**

```
intent.putExtra(String key, Object data);
```

**Main Activity**

```
intent.getExtra(String key);
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a good idea. The official android website suggests my understanding of the back button to be the correct understanding so overwriting functionality should not be necessary, nor should it be advised as it will cause problems in different scenarios. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: yes it is not ,but hey it does the work for a while ,just so it won't slow you down :) hope you find the right way !

Answer (score 0):

SO while not understanding the bug fully, I have found that the issue is related to two things. The AVD I was using and the activity name. On the original AVD I changed the activity name from ActivityDetail to ActivityDetail2 and this fixed the entire problem. I realized something was up w/ the activity when creating a third activity didn't have the issue. Unfortunately upon changing the name back (shift + f6 in Android studio) the problem began to occur again. Perplexed I then deleted the AVD (had to reinstall android studio to fix emulator:process failed for error code 0 error) and created a new one with a different phone type and different version of android. I was then able to run the application w/ the activity name "ActivityDetail" and the problem didn't occur.

I was also not able to re-create the issue on the original AVD. This tells me that something on the AVD was associated to that specific activity name, set somehow through an application call I might have made while following the guide on the official android notification page: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Unfortunately that's all I can say for certain. That and there's no need to overwrite the on back key action just to fix this issue.